# What is RNA in scala?

Tags: scala, collections

I am reading about scala collection [architecture](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html). RNA term is mentioned here. Can somebody explain what it is?

Comment: About **closing** this question. English is not my native language, so when I read RNA I thought about some programming term not biology term. For native speakers this question may be not insteresting, while for others who use English language as foreign language it can be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA):

> Ribonucleic acid (RNA) is a polymeric molecule implicated in various biological roles in coding, decoding, regulation, and expression of genes. RNA and DNA are nucleic acids, and, along with proteins and carbohydrates, constitute the three major macromolecules essential for all known forms of life. [...] Cellular organisms use messenger RNA (mRNA) to convey genetic information (using the letters G, U, A, and C to denote the nitrogenous bases guanine, uracil, adenine, and cytosine) that directs synthesis of specific proteins.

Of course this has nothing to do with Scala or programming as such - it is merely used as a real-life example in the tutorial you're reading.

Answer (score 0):

It's an example problem domain used in that article. From [there](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html#integrating-a-new-collection-rna-sequences):

> In the next few sections you’ll be walked through two examples that do this, namely sequences of RNA bases and prefix maps implemented with Patricia tries.

If you want to learn more about RNA, check out its [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA).